Which strike is the sweet spot for monetizing implied-realized vol?
I actually have two related questions:

Are there articles discussing my question? I'd be interested in not only empirical studies, but especially (semi-) analytical or closed form solutions or approximations and discussions. I have searched for some time, but haven't been able to find anything that really addresses my question.

Due to my inability to find a research paper on this, I am wondering if the following idea of mine will do as a first stab, please feel free to point out errors:


By the most likely path approximation the IV can be written as
$$
I^2(K,T) \approx E^\mathbb Q \left[ \left. \frac1T \int_0^T \sigma^2_t dt \right| S_T=K \right]
$$
where $\sigma_t$ denotes the stochastic spot vol.
Suppose now that one has the following forecast / one can evaluate the following expectation:
$$
E^\mathbb P \left[ \left. \frac1T \int_0^T \sigma^2_t dt \right| S_T=K \right].
$$
Is the sweet spot then the strike where
$$
E^\mathbb P \left[ \left. \frac1T \int_0^T \sigma^2_t dt \right| S_T=K \right] - E^\mathbb Q \left[ \left. \frac1T \int_0^T \sigma^2_t dt \right| S_T=K \right]
$$
is maximized? Would this be a reasonable assumption and departure point?
The same idea for sweet spot along time to maturity axis instead of strike axis.
(Of course also welcome to drop me a message directly if the topic interests you but you can't discuss it here.)

I have no mathematical proof of it but I suspect that the portfolio used to hedge a Varswap (all strikes, with a position proportional to 1/K at each strike) is the ideal portfolio for taking advantage of an implied var greater than realized.

@nbbo2 Thanks, agree that the $1/K^2$ portfolio is a clean way to capture it. But sometimes that many options are not available and one would like to analyze a limited number of strikes only.

In the standard Black–Scholes setting, let $S_t$ be the price of an underlying asset at time $t$. A European call option on $S_t$ with strike $K$ and maturity $T$ has an arbitrage-free price given by the Black–Scholes formula
$$C_0(K) \;=\; S_0\,\Phi(d_1) - K\,e^{-rT}\,\Phi(d_2),$$
where
$$
d_1
\;=\;
\frac{\ln\!\bigl(\tfrac{S_0}{K}\bigr) + \bigl(r + \tfrac12 \sigma^2\bigr)\,T}{\sigma\,\sqrt{T}},
\quad
d_2
\;=\;
d_1 - \sigma \sqrt{T},
$$
and $\sigma=\sigma(K,T)$ is the implied volatility. The realized volatility over $[0,T]$ is
$$
\widehat{\sigma}_{\mathrm{real}}
\;=\;
\sqrt{\frac{1}{T}\,\int_0^T \Bigl(\tfrac{d S_t}{S_t}\Bigr)^2}.
$$
To monetize the difference between implied volatility $\sigma(K,T)$ and realized volatility $\widehat{\sigma}_{\mathrm{real}}$, we often focus on the expected profit-and-loss (PnL) of being long or short an option and continuously delta-hedging. Under a risk-neutral approximation, the expected PnL from a continuously hedged position can be approximated (to first order) by
$$
\mathbb{E}[\mathrm{PnL}]
\;\approx\;
\tfrac12\,\bigl(\widehat{\sigma}_{\mathrm{real}}^2 \;-\; \sigma^2(K,T)\bigr)\,\Gamma_{\!\mathrm{eff}},
$$
where $\Gamma_{\!\mathrm{eff}} \approx \int_0^T \Gamma(S_t,K)\,\tfrac{dt}{T}$ is the time-averaged gamma.
We can solve
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial K}\,\Bigl[\, \bigl(\widehat{\sigma}_{\mathrm{real}}^2 - \sigma^2(K,T)\bigr)\,\Gamma_{\!\mathrm{eff}}(K) \Bigr]
\;=\; 0
$$
to locate the "sweet spot" in strike. The first term $\widehat{\sigma}_{\mathrm{real}}^2 - \sigma^2(K,T)$ encapsulates the volatility-risk premium, while the second term $\Gamma_{\!\mathrm{eff}}(K)$ accounts for the option's curvature. Because $\Gamma_{\!\mathrm{eff}}(K)$ is sharply peaked near at-the-money and $\sigma(K,T)$ typically increases as $K$ moves away from the forward (due to skew/smile effects), we often find that the optimal strike is slightly inside the region where the implied-vol–realized-vol gap remains significantly positive but the option still retains substantial gamma exposure. Under mild skew and moderate tail risk, this often coincides with a strike near the forward—particularly for short-dated tenors—making slightly in-the-money or slightly out-of-the-money options near the forward price the best candidates for harvesting the implied–realized premium.
For finding optimal strike points in your forecast framework, while simply maximizing the difference
$$
\Delta(K)
\;=\;
E^\mathbb{P}\!\Bigl[
\tfrac1T \int_0^T \sigma_t^2 \,dt
\;\Big|\;
S_T = K
\Bigr]
\;-\;
E^\mathbb{Q}\!\Bigl[
\tfrac1T \int_0^T \sigma_t^2 \,dt
\;\Big|\;
S_T = K
\Bigr]
$$
would identify strikes where the market's implied path variance differs most from your real-world forecast, a better approach is to weight this by the option's effective gamma:
$$\Delta(K)\,\times\,\Gamma_{\!\mathrm{eff}}(K)$$
This weighting matters because large variance differences at far OTM strikes may not generate meaningful PnL due to low gamma exposure.
The same principle applies when searching across maturities $T$, where you weight the difference
$$
E^\mathbb{P}\!\Bigl[
\tfrac1T \int_0^T \sigma_t^2\,dt
\Bigr]
\;-\;
E^\mathbb{Q}\Bigl[
\tfrac1T \int_0^T \sigma_t^2\,dt
\Bigr]
$$
by the relevant option sensitivities to identify optimal trading points in time.​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Thanks +1. I contemplated $\frac{\partial}{\partial K},\Bigl[, \bigl(\widehat{\sigma}{\mathrm{real}}^2 - \sigma^2(K,T)\bigr),\Gamma{!\mathrm{eff}}(K) \Bigr]
;=; 0$ but not so sure it's the easiest approach. Regarding your comment "a better approach is to weight this by the option's effective gamma:", the most likely path is roughly speaking already the path of maximum gamma, so not sure I need to weigh it again by gamma, will mull over it.

extract from Wilmott  Introduction to Quantitative Finance  Paul Wilmott
I strongly suggest you buy the book. The book is basic knowledge for quantitative traders, Hull is a text, Wilmott is a practitioners book.
